# nvim-lspconfig omnifunc opens preview window

Tags: lsp, previewwindow

Having configured `nvim-lspconfig` exactly as [officially recommended](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/README.md#suggested-configuration), I want to use the completion functionality via omnifunc.

When pressing `<C-X><C-O>`, a drop down window appears right below my cursor position with options to select. On the other hand, another Window named `Preview` opens above my current buffer window with two empty lines. **Is this intended, and if not, how can I fix it?**

I feel like in this preview window should be a description and syntax information about various functions and packages. This problem arises with `pyright` (Python) as well as `clangd` (C++), so I suspect it is a neovim problem.

Comment: Does `completeopt` contain `preview`? Still, the preview window should be populated by something if it is opens

Answer (score 2):

This happens when `completeopt` has the `preview` option in it. You probably added this to your config at one point.

Check `verbose set completeopt?` to see its contents and where it was last set from, so you can remove it from your config. If it's being set by a plugin and you want to explicitly disable it, use `set completeopt-=preview`.

Comment: In neovim it's `vim.opt.completeopt = { "menu" }`. See `:help completeopt` for all of the options.